# "on-shell" and "off-shell" in French

Tags: traduction, anglais, terminologie, physique

I've searched a lot and asked lots of physicists (but not French native speakers) about the proper use of the physics term "[on-shell/off-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_shell_and_off_shell)" in French, but I haven't found an answer yet. For example, how to say in French: *this theorem is on-shell theorem* (e.g. Noether's), or *this term might vanish on-shell*.

Comment: Evidence of a research attempt would be appreciated

Comment: In physics, the "on-shell/off-shell" terms are widely used. For example: this theorem is on-shell theorem (e.g Noether's), or "this term" will vanish on-shell. So I want to know how to say that in French.

Comment: @BenKnoble I've searched everywhere, asked lots of physicists who know french (but not native speakers).. unfortunately, nothing helped.

Comment: Consider editing that info into your question so it's clear to others.

Comment: ok I've edited it.. merci :)

Comment: Une recherche sur google sur "*physique quantique "on shell" site:fr*" montre un certain nombre de documents utilisant "on-shell" ou "off-shell" sans traduction - ils semble donc correct de traduire par: *ce théorème est "on-shell"* - je ne suis pas physicien.

Comment: @assylias C'est un peu l'approche de la version italienne de l'entrée _Wikipédia_ (voir en bas à gauche de la page) dans la question, mais j'aimerais tout de même savoir comment on rend le _shell_ en français et comprendre l'usage... Par ailleurs n'hésitez pas à répondre dans le sens de votre commentaire !

Comment: It's a common practice in specific fields to take terms in other languages without translating them. I would not be surprised if French physicists said "*on-shell*" without translating it.

Comment: I disagree with previous comments. I am convinced on/off-shell has a translation since I have never used it in French. @Milou Can you give  very clear example (a whole sentence, or paragraph). "Shell" could be used to describe limits to a theorem of simple "coque" in finite element models...

Comment: @ThomasGuenet I've never used "on/off-shell" in French as well. I think that we have been using its meaning in the context. Now I am convinced that we have two options: use it as it is or understand what does it mean in the context and translate this meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd also recommend to use "on-shell" and "off-shell" as is.

The Italian and Spanish page also use the untranslated terms, and it's common to keep some terms untranslated when it's not easy to translate them (even in English, words like [eigenvalue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) for example.)

If you're not convinced, to stay in quantum mechanics, we also use "spin" untranslated in French, you probably know that.

It's the same for [quarks](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark), we say "*quark up, down, strange, charm, ...*" Like other said, most scientists of the field speak at least enough English to understand those terms, and it's often just convenient to keep them as they are.

Answer (score 2):

Pour ce qui est de la physique à ce niveau, on peut supposer que tous les intervenants maitrisent l'anglais, et une expression telle que "on-shell/off-shell" sera probablement adoptée telle quelle.

Si vous voulez vraiment un mot français dans ce contexte, je proposerais "enveloppe" pour "shell".

Answer (score 1):

J'ai fait quelques recherches sur internet concernant cette question, et bien qu'on trouve certains papiers universitaires avec la reprise du terme "on-shell", il existe peut-être une traduction en français (si je ne fais pas erreur! Ceci n'étant pas du tout mon domaine.)

Ayant fait la comparaison de la page wikipédia en français et en anglais. Les occurrences du mot "symétrie" donnent ça:

> Symétries d'espace-temps, dites « externes »

> Symétries internes

Source: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_Noether_(physique)

À comparer avec la version en anglais:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether's_theorem

> If this holds on shell and off shell, we say Q generates an off-shell symmetry.

Par contre, certains documents parlent à la fois de "on-shell" et de symétrie "externe".

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.5736.pdf

> Fonction de partition on-shell du système séparée

> Il peut exister d’autres symétries externes, auxquelles on se réfère
>   en CFT

PS: Je supprimerai ma réponse si je suis à côté de la plaque.

Ce que je propose à la personne qui a posé cette question, c'est de me donner toutes les occurrences de l'expression "off-shell" ou "on-shell". C'est-à-dire tous les mots qui l'accompagnent dans une expression. Par exemple, "symétrie off-shell". À quel autre mot cette expression est-elle directement liée?  Ça permettrait de faire une recherche avec l'équivalent en français dans des articles universitaires ou des thèses portant sur le même sujet...

Comment: je crois que vous êtes un peu à côté de la plaque, si je peux me permettre (je connais un peu de QM :-) - ce que vous dites est très bien pour le théorème de Noether, mais je ne crois pas que ce soit lié à on-shell/off-shell.

Comment: Merci pour votre recherche concernant ma question. Mais que vous avez trouvé est une traduction "locale" de on/off-shell. C'est à dire ils ont traduit le synonyme de on-shell dans le contexte. Mais on ne peut pas le généraliser dans toutes les autres occurrences.

Comment: En physique, "on/off-shell" peut être utilisée dans plusieurs cas. Je suis maintenant convaincue qu'il n'y a pas une traduction directe. On-shell et off-shell sont utilisés en français. Si quelqu'un veut les traduire, il les traduira selon le contexte, qui varie d'un cas à l'autres.

Comment: Bon tant pis. J'ai tenté le coup pourtant... Mauvaise pioche, je supprimerai donc...